# Write sql query to linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am having following query in `sql` :

```
SELECT [definition],[pos]
  FROM [WordNet].[dbo].[synsets]
  where synsetid in(SELECT [synsetid] FROM [WordNet].[dbo].[senses] 
  where wordid = (select [wordid]FROM [WordNet].[dbo].[words]
  where lemma = 'searchString'))
```

**I had tried this for sql to linq :**

```
long x = 0;

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
{
    var word = from w in db.words
               where w.lemma == searchString
               select w.wordId;
    x = word.First();

   var sence = from s in db.senses
               where (s.senseId == x)
               select s;
   var synset = from syn in db.synsets
                where sence.Contains(syn.synsetId)
                select syn;
```

But I am getting following error at `sence.Contains()`

```
  Error1:Instance argument: cannot convert from
  'System.Linq.IQueryable<WordNetFinal.Models.sense>' to
  'System.Linq.ParallelQuery<int>'
```

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

Below code:

```
var sence = from s in db.senses
               where (s.senseId == x)
               select s;
```

Returns object of type: `WordNetFinal.Models.sense`, but in `where sence.Contains(syn.synsetId)` you are trying to search in it `syn.synsetId` which is an integer.

So you should change above code to:

```
var sence = from s in db.senses
                   where (s.senseId == x)
                   select s.senseId;
```

Answer (score 0):

x seems to be of Word type, which is not the type of Id (probably int or long).

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing an entire `sense` row with a `synsetId`, which is not correct. You're also splitting the original query into two separate queries by using `First()` which triggers an evaluation of the expression so far. If you can live with not returning an SQL error if there are duplicates in `words`, you can write the query as something like this;

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
{
    var wordIds = from word in db.words
                  where word.lemma == searchString
                  select word.wordId;

    var synsetIds = from sense in db.senses
                    where wordIds.Contains(sense.wordId)
                    select sense.synsetId;

    var result = (from synset in db.synsets
                  where synsetIds.Contains(synset.synsetId)
                  select new {synset.definition, synset.pos}).ToList(); 
}
```

The `ToList()` triggering the evaluation once for the entire query.

You could also just do it using a simpler join;

```
var result = (from synset in db.synsets
              join sense in db.senses on synset.synsetId equals sense.synsetId
              join word in db.words on sense.wordId equals word.wordId
              select new {synset.definition, synset.pos}).ToList();
```